# When using a docked element with a scrollable element in a fit layout container in sencha 2, why does my scrolling break sometimes?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

weird problem here that I haven't found any info for online.

When I create a layout like this in Sencha Touch 2:

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.Sample", {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    config :
    {
        layout : 'fit',
        scrollable : false,
        items : 
        [
        {
            xtype : 'container',
            docked : 'top',
            html: '<div>Stuff</div>'
        },
        {
            xtype : 'container',
            scrollable : true,
            html: '<div> Bunch of Stuff here that takes a lot of vertical space </div>'

        }
        ]
    },
});
```

Everything seems to work like I want most of the time.  The stuff in the first item is docked and fixed up on top of the screen, and the tall content of the second item is scrollable.  In testing though, sometimes if I scroll up and down quickly and click on items I am able to "break" the scrolling, where the second item seems to forget where its top is.  The top of the content in the second item is cut off when scrolled all the way up.  Interestingly enough, It seems like a chunk of blank space equal to the cut off height is added to the bottom of the second item.

What could I be doing wrong to cause this behavior ?  Like I said it doesn't happen every time, but I can usually reproduce it with 4 or 5 attempts.

Thanks for looking!

UPDATE:
Through more testing, it looks like this is somehow tied to re-sizing the browser window -- possibly while the scroll animation is still going.  Also, I am pretty sure that this popped up in my Chrome console log when this occurred:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of null      Abstract.js:85
Ext.define.doSetHidden                                      Abstract.js:85
Ext.define.doSet                                            Evented.js:63
Ext.define.doFire                                           Controller.js:197
Ext.define.fire                                             Controller.js:124
Ext.define.doDispatchEvent                                  Dispatcher.js:341
Ext.define.dispatchEvent                                    Dispatcher.js:322
Ext.define.doFireEvent                                      Observable.js:235
Ext.define.fireAction                                       Observable.js:224
(anonymous function)                                        Evented.js:32
Ext.define.hide                                             Component.js:1682
Ext.define.doHideIndicators                                 View.js:225
method                                                      sencha-touch.js:3127
```

Comment: could you upload your screenshot here?

Comment: Well, a screenshot doesn't really capture the problem.  If no one has any answers and this is still plaguing me I'll try to make a video at some point and link it.  I did already find some more info on this though that I am posting to the original question.

Comment: it's quite hard to address the problem but `layout: 'fit'` is not stable always. If you do not really need to use it, simple use `card` layout or simply let it `auto`. Also, you should specify `scrollable` config for your docked container. Hope it helps.